# Running into context error

Tags: python, scripting, tracking

Im trying to get this tracking script for running in the background working. It was working perfectly in the background until I got to the filter tracks portion. Here is the script:

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'CLIP_EDITOR':
        override = bpy.context.copy()
        override['area'] = area
        bpy.ops.clip.detect_features(override, threshold = 0.05, min_distance = 25)
        print('Markers Detected')
        bpy.ops.clip.track_markers(override, sequence=True)
        print('Tracked Forward')
        bpy.ops.clip.track_markers(override, sequence=True, backwards=True)
        print('Tracked Backwards')
        totalFrames = bpy.context.scene.frame_end = bpy.context.scene.frame_start
        bpy.ops.clip.clean_tracks(override, frames=(totalFrames + 1), error=0.5, action='DELETE_TRACK')
        #Can get to here fine, error occurs when doing this filter track function
        bpy.ops.clip.filter_tracks(override['area'], track_threshold=5)
        bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath="/Applications/blender2.76" + "test.blend")
        break
```

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

[image]

This is currently what the errors are looking like now for this.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add/6105#6105

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
bpy.ops.clip.filter_tracks(override['area'], track_threshold=5)
```

To:

```
bpy.ops.clip.filter_tracks(track_threshold=5)
```

And see if that works.

I'm not that familiar with what you are doing, however the reason I believe that you need to take out the extra argument is because of inspecting the auto-complete of the function when I enter it in directly at the console (it just seems like there is a problem with passing more than the threshold value - See Below):

[image]

After looking into this a little further, try just commenting this line out.

From the Manual it is meant to smooth out spikes in the track, the problem with this (this context) is: you just deleted the **"spike"** in your previous line of code, so there is no track to even deal with.

**Or**

Maybe you just need to check and see if the previous statement deleted the track. Then set a variable to indicate if the track was deleted, then you can make a decision to filter it or not based on that.

Comment: I think the override still belongs to match what was used in previous ops. But it should be `override` not `override['area']`.

Comment: Just made an edit to the post to show the errors I get from terminal. I appreciate your guys help, will keep working at this but if you have any more ideas that would be greatly appreciated.